# Systemd is installed on Ubuntu Raring?

Tags: 13.04, upstart

Systemd appears to be installed in Ubuntu Raring. What does it provide that upstart doesn't provide? Why is it there? I thought Ubuntu was keeping upstart.

Comment: *"Systemd appears to be installed"* Please share why you think it is installed. (what indicates this?) It's [*available*](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?section=all&arch=any&keywords=systemd&searchon=names) since the Raring release, but that doesn't mean you need to install it.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu Raring is using Upstart 1.8 and they mention it in changelog https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RaringRingtail/ReleaseNotes#Upstart_1.8

Comparison of features by systemd developers http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/why.html

Answer (score 0):

systemd provides various services for such things as power management and login management which are preferred to the existing packages such as pm-utils and ConsoleKit. Upstart will continue to be used for the service control and management, and a "shim" is used to allow the useful systemd-services to run without [the main part of systemd](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=4VA5fcEFsNQC&lpg=PA167&ots=2EE7ZtFlIc&dq=systemd%20shim%20ubuntu&pg=PA167#v=onepage&q=systemd%20shim%20ubuntu&f=false).